# Result set returns the default value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
select top 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventtime desc) as id,
Eventcode, eventtime as et, status from cfw.dbo.DCTBLEVENTINFO 
where MeterID = 4722 and EventTime between convert(date,'2011-10-21') 
and dateadd(day,1,convert(date,'2011-10-26')) 
and EventCode = 13
```

**Original resultset:**

```
id  Eventcode   et                    status
1   13        2011-10-26 15:00:00.000   1
```

The above query returns the perfect result set, but if I use the same query like the following manner it returns the wrong result

```
SELECT temp.et 
  FROM (SELECT TOP 1 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventtime desc) as id,
               Eventcode, 
               eventtime as et, 
               status 
          FROM cfw.dbo.DCTBLEVENTINFO 
         WHERE MeterID = 4722 
           AND EventTime BETWEEN CONVERT(date,'2011-10-21') 
                             AND DATEADD(day,1,convert(date,'2011-10-26')) 
           AND EventCode = 13) temp 
 WHERE status = 1
```

**Result set for the above query :**

```
et
------------------------
2011-10-21 21:42:00.000
```

It returns some other date. I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an ORDER BY to your sub select.

Something like

```
select  temp.et 
from    (
            select  top 1 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventtime desc) as id, 
                    Eventcode, 
                    eventtime as et, 
                    status 
            from    cfw.dbo.DCTBLEVENTINFO  
            where   MeterID = 4722 
            and     EventTime between convert(date,'2011-10-21') and dateadd(day,1,convert(date,'2011-10-26'))  
            and     EventCode = 13
            ORDER BY eventtime desc
        )   temp 
where   status=1
```

Please always remember [Without ORDER BY, there is no default sort order.](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx)

Furthermore, remeber the [Logical Query Processing Phases – Order of Statement Execution](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/)

> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. OUTER
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. CUBE | ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 temp.et from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY eventtime desc) as id,
Eventcode, eventtime as et, status from cfw.dbo.DCTBLEVENTINFO 
where MeterID = 4722 and EventTime between convert(date,'2011-10-21') 
and dateadd(day,1,convert(date,'2011-10-26')) 
and EventCode = 13 ORDER BY eventtime desc)temp where status=1
```

Instead of restricting only one row in subquery, get the complete result, check for status and restrict first row alone.